# Are there any consequences/effects from not using blinkers?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

So, yes. I'm using blinkers when turning right or left in the road, just like what I should do IRL.

I just want to ask if there're any events that may occur if I don't use them, like problems in driving, penalties in delivery, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what i have found they do have an influence although not a very strong one on traffic as follows, btw this was done through my own testing which i can produce video for if needed.

- indicators don't influence in any way the cars which are directly
  behind you
- They sometimes influence cars in the lane next to you, this is most
  prominant if your lane is ending.
- The most obvious influence i have seen is with oncoming traffic which
  i have found will only let you turn if you have your indicator on.

I know it is a shame that indicators don't work how they should but if you do a search you can find several "realistic" indicator mods to improve this.

Hope this helped